# Solve an ODE $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\cot x\frac{dy}{dx}+4y\csc^2x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\cot x\frac{dy}{dx}+4y\csc^2x=0$$

I could not find any examples as to how to approach 2nd order ODEs with trigonometric coefficients.

How do I solve the auxiliary equation and get the complementary function ? Please assist.

There are no initial conditions given. The answer given is: $\displaystyle y=k_1\cos\left(2\log\tan\frac{x}{2}+k_2\right)$.

Wolframalpha gives a different answer: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27[x]+%2B+Cot[x]+y%27[x]+%2B+4+y[x]+Csc[x]^2%3D0

Comment: This is a second order ODE. You need at least two initial conditions.

Comment: There are no initial conditions given. The answer given is: $\displaystyle y=k_1\cos\left(2\log\tan\frac{x}{2}+k_2\right)$.

Comment: I do not think I can guess this solution. I suppose you need some special techniques to get this closed form solution.

Comment: I haven't tried it but you may try substituting $z=y\cot x$.

Comment: Both Mathematica and Maple give different answer from what you have, and they both give different answers from each others. Maple: `eq := diff(y(x), `$`(x, 2))+cot(x)*(diff(y(x), x))+4*y(x)*csc(x)^2;sol:=dsolve(eq,y(x));` gives `sol := y(x) = _C1*((csc(x)-cot(x))^I)^2+_C2/((csc(x)-cot(x))^I)^2` and M `eq = y''[x] + Cot[x] y'[x] + 4 y[x] Csc[x]^2; y[x] /. First@DSolve[eq == 0, y[x], x]` gives `C[1] Cos[2 (Log[Cos[x/2]] - Log[Sin[x/2]])] - C[2] Sin[2 (Log[Cos[x/2]] - Log[Sin[x/2]])]`

Comment: wondering whether there is some typo in the question..

Comment: @square_one: Have you tried using the substitution that I mentioned?

Comment: it brought a cosecx cot x and didn't look like it was going anywhere .. but yes .. some substitution should do the trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for a solution of the form $y=f(g(x))$.

If $y$ is a solution then, a chain rule exercise, will show, 
$$ (g')^2 f''  + (g'' + g'\cot x)f' + 4\csc^2 x f  = 0 $$
Now we apply ***wishful thinking***. We hope that we can arrange such a $g(x)$ so that the above DE will have constant coefficients. In fact, we can always normalize with a constant multiple so that after we divide out by $(g')^2$ coefficient we will be left with $1$ as the coefficient for $f$. For that we require, 
$$ (g')^2 = 4\csc^2 x \implies g' = 2\csc x \implies g = -2\log (\csc x + \cot x)$$
Now look at the middle term. Since $g' = 2\csc x$ we have $g'' = -2\csc x\cot x$ and so we get that $(g'' + g'\cot x) = (-2\csc x \cot x + 2\csc x \cot x ) = 0$. Thus, we are left with, 
$$ f'' + f = 0 $$
We can pick $f = \sin(x)$ as one of the solutions. Now we can check that, 
$$ y = \sin \big( 2\log(\csc x + \cot x) \big) $$
Works!