# If analytical solvers fail in solving an ODE, does it mean that it is unlikely have an analytical solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maple, mathematica

If analytical solvers (For example, Mathematica and Maple) fail to solve an ODE (Here, I have such situation with the ODE I have given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105156/how-to-find-the-solution-of-this-second-order-differential-equation-with-the-tim): second order ODE with time-dependent coefficients), does it mean that it is unlikely to have an analytical solution without any approximations to further simplify it?

Comment: "unlikely" is somewhat poorly defined. I know what you mean, but maybe you should think of a more precise question. You can make a few tests yourself by creating weird functions, deriving them a few times, making weird manipulations and computing the result. Then you create an ODE by performing the same operations on a generic function and equaling the generic result to the one you've obtained previously. I'm unaware of a statement of the classes of ODEs that can or can't be solved by these proprietary software packages.

Comment: Thanks @Mefitico, I am struggling to find a proper word here. What I have now is a second order ODE with time-dependent coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maple and Mathematica both contain decision procedures for certain classes of ODEs. The decision procedures all have *shape*: If ODE $L$ belongs to class X (linear, for example) with coefficients from class Y (frequently, polynomial in the dependent variable), and one is looking for solutions in class Z (polynomial, rational, exp-log, hypergeometric, *elementary*, etc), then such algorithms will either return an answer or sufficient evidence to prove that there is none.

These algorithms are called by the default de solver routine -- but of course, the default one does not return that evidence of failure in that case. For that, you need to call the exposed in sub-packages decision procedures themselves.

Note that I never said *analytical solution* anywhere above, as that is ill-defined, as others have pointed out. Are Heun functions allowed in closed-form solutions? People disagree (for good reason) about that. Thus the need for more precision.

Having said that, if neither Maple nor Mathematica find a closed-form solution for you ODE, finding a generic closed-form solution is likely to require very significant work, if it exists at all. Neither are foolproof, but they sure are good.